# Microsoft Outlook 7 with Windows XP - various problems

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, user-profiles, file-search

I have various issues with Outlook at the present time. First of all, in trying to fix one problem I have created a couple more. When I open Outlook now it asks me which profile I want to open... this is because of a suggested fix that I attempted that didn't work. It doesn't matter the amount of times I set the current one as the Default one in the drop box that comes up as every time I open it up it obliges me to select the profile that I want.

Then, which is the initial problem that I still have not been able to resolve, when I reply to emails from certain people their address does not automatically appear in the "TO" box. Which means I have to copy and paste which is a pain... I send a lot of emails in a day!

Thirdly, my search does not work. I trace the appearance of these issues back to the installation of PC Tools, which has been an awesome instrument in keeping my system clear of viruses, etc, however, it appears to have messed up my Outlook... I have tried, with one of their technicians to uninstall the program to see if my problems resolved, but they didn't so they are blaming Microsoft... can anyone help please?

Comment: How big is your PST? This sounds like a classic oversized PST file issue... Even though MS says you can have PSTs larger then 2GB. Experience tells me that it's a terrible Idea to go any larger (at least in 03-07). http://serverfault.com/questions/197024/how-to-manage-bandwidth-for-cached-exchange-mode/198742#198742

Answer (score 1):

First off I would check there are no add-ons enabled.  Check the Outlook Security Centre and disable any non-Microsoft add-ons.

You may find that this resolves all your problems but if not we'll deal with them one by one.

1. Being prompted for profile -
   Go into Control Panel... Mail... Show Profiles - Remove any you don't need
2. Names not appearing in the To box.  This is caused by a corrupt NK2 file, rename your NK2 file and start again.

   - Close Outlook
   - Rename C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\.nk2 to .nk2.old
   - Open Outlook and manually enter an address and send the mail
   - Close and re-open Outlook and check that this address auto-completes now
     If you need to recover the addresses from your old NK2 file then use the utilities from NirSoft http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html
3. Search not working.  This could well be a corrupt PST file as Kyle suggested.  Check the size of the PST file (same location as the NK2) and try running scanpst on it.